# None values after handle ValueError in a request?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I am making some requests to an API which [postag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) the [following text](https://pastebin.com/sWgR1K3g) as follows:

```
def pos(text):
    payload = {'key': 'thekey', 'of': 'json', 'ilang': 'ES', \
               'txt': text, \
               'tt': 'a', \
               'uw': 'y', 'lang': 'es'}

    r = requests.get('http://api.meaningcloud.com/parser-2.0', params=payload, stream = True)
    return r.json()
```

At the beginning, it gave me a `ValueError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ac09c6405340> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 df['tags'] = df['tweets'].apply(transform)
      3 df

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2292             else:
   2293                 values = self.asobject
-> 2294                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2295 
   2296         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:66124)()

<ipython-input-18-707ac7b399b4> in transform(a_lis)
     25 
     26 def transform(a_lis):
---> 27     analysis = pos(str(a_lis))
     28     a_list = parse_tree(analysis['token_list'], [])
     29     return a_list

<ipython-input-18-707ac7b399b4> in pos(text)
      8 
      9     r = requests.get('http://api.meaningcloud.com/parser-2.0', params=payload, stream = True)
---> 10     return r.json()
     11 
     12 def parse_tree(token, a_list):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    864                     # used.
    865                     pass
--> 866         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    867 
    868     @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, use_decimal, **kw)
    514             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None
    515             and not use_decimal and not kw):
--> 516         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    517     if cls is None:
    518         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w, _PY3)
    368         if _PY3 and isinstance(s, binary_type):
    369             s = s.decode(self.encoding)
--> 370         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
    371         end = _w(s, end).end()
    372         if end != len(s):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx, _w, _PY3)
    398             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
    399                 idx += 3
--> 400         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Therefore I handled the exception and applied it to a pandas dataframe column with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../data.csv')
df['tagged_text'] = df['tweets'].apply(transform)
```

However, with some instances (columns) I got `None`:

```
text                                                tagged_text
Siento que estoy en un cuarto oscuro y hay sil...   [(sentar, VI-S1PSABL-N4), (que, CSSN9), (estar...
Los mejores de @UEoficial Sebastián Jaime, Sey...    None
#ColoColoJuegaEnEl13 la primera y adentro mier...    None
Juguito heladoooo de melón: me siento se...          None
@sxfiacrespo @lunasoledadhern Hola Luna...          [(@sxfiacrespo @lunasoledadhern, NPUU-N-), (ho...
```

Thus, my question is why at some texts (columns) I am getting `None` and how can I correctly tag those `None` instances?. Note that I made some tests and there is no problem with the text, since for those `None` a json with all the tagged content is returned. For [example consider this function application](https://pastebin.com/fa5Eczxc).

Comment: Sounds like you did `r.json[]` instead (square brackets). No, a method object is indeed not subscriptable, but it *is* callable. Make sure you use `()` (round parentheses)!

Comment: Please don't edit changes from my answer into your question; that invalidates my answer and leaves future visitors perplexed as to what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does next to nothing:

```
except ValueError:
    np.nan
```

That only references the `np.nan` object. If you want to return it, you need to do so explicitly:

```
except ValueError:
    return np.nan
```

otherwise the function just.. ends, which means `None` is returned.

Other notes:

```
r = requests.get('http://api.meaningcloud.com/parser-2.0', data=payload, stream = True)
json_data = json.dumps(r.json())
data = yaml.load(json_data)
return data
```

is a really expensive way of spelling

```
r = requests.post('http://api.meaningcloud.com/parser-2.0', data=payload)
return r.json()
```

Loading JSON into Python, then producing JSON again, then using a YAML parser to turn the JSON back to Python is somewhat excessive. I also removed the `stream=True`; that's only needed when you want to process the response data as a stream (which the `response.json()` method doesn't do).

According to the [API documentation](https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/lemmatization-pos-parsing/doc/2.0/request), `txt` is supposed to be a single string.I'd not  use `str(a_lis)` to produce that; if you have a list of strings, just join those into one long string with `' '.join(a_lis)`. However, I'm sure that `pandas.Series.apply()` passes in individual values (e.g. strings) to your function, at which point there is no need to join anything at all (but your `a_lis` variable name *is* very confusing in that case).

The API also specifies that it uses *POST* requests (I'm surprised they accept GET still anyway). Using a `POST` request (`requests.post()`) will allow you to send much larger pieces of text for analysis. Use the `data` keyword. I've used the correct syntax in my last sample above.

That you used GET is also the reason you get a `ValueError`:

```
>>> r  = requests.get('http://api.meaningcloud.com/parser-2.0', params=payload)
>>> r.status_code
414
>>> r.reason
'Request-URI Too Long'
>>> r = requests.post('http://api.meaningcloud.com/parser-2.0', data=payload)
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Comment: @J.Do: I can't help with your `ValueError` unless you can provide a sample data set (make it small) that reproduces that error.

Comment: @J.Do: that's not really a small sample data set; I was hoping for the return value of `api_call()`, reduced to a minimal example for which `parse_tree()` returns `np.nan`.

Comment: @J.Do: it looks like the `ValueError` comes from your use of requests, because I can't reproduce it with my code.

Comment: So using `text = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/11QMa5Jy').text.strip("'")` first, then using your `payload` dictionary, with `analysis = requests.post('http://api.meaningcloud.com/parser-2.0', data=payload).json()` and `parse_tree(analysis['token_list'], [])`, returns a list of tuples.

Comment: @J.Do: You could just remove the `try:...except:` and include the full traceback this produces in your post, so I can confirm..

Comment: I edited and removed the `try/except` from the question, now it is reproducible, thanks!

Comment: @J.Do: yup, that's because you are using GET, not POST. The server gives you a 414 *Request-URI Too Long* error, which is why I strongly urge you to use POST requests (which are not limited by URL length).

Comment: Thanks.. this was very helpful!